# My profile picture seems to have vanished?

Tags: support

My profile picture (or whatever the kids are calling it today) is gone and I don't have another one to upload. Is there a stored copy somewhere? That took me a long time to make.

Answer (score 0):

I found copies of your previous profile pictures here:

- https://i.stack.imgur.com/JZEl9.jpg
- https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/4de3df4fa010cd20c1c226fda92b3b83?s=512&d=identicon&r=PG

But please don't use, on this site, the one that's a modified version of an image of Hitler (see also [As a moderator, how do I handle a potentially inappropriate profile picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243285/139866)).

Comment: Thank you for finding it but that isn't Hitler, it's Angulimala. You can tell by the "Metta smile" and the title "Metta for Bullies" that it isn't the Hitler like you are thinking. The point is to remind people that we are Hitler and Hitler can change into Angulimala.  I love that picture because it's a teaching in itself. It makes me feel that if this horrible guy can do it, then so can everyone. You would have known this is someone would have asked.  I'm a little offended that you think so little of me that I would put a picture up for the purpose of offending people.

Comment: I've little or no insight into why you posted it (and I don't assume that you did it "for the purpose of offending people"); but if (or because) other people react to it, it's easier (less work) for me and for other moderators if don't use it.

Comment: Really you don't? Then I should appoligize, sorry :) This comment is reasonable enough I suppose, maybe I am the one who is  assuming things, huh? I know you are well intentioned.

Comment: Please, the next time you have no insight maybe you could ask me? ...anyway I just told you and then you say you have no insight? I'm kinda surprised by that. What am I missing here? :)

Answer (score 0):

I removed your picture 2 days ago while at the same time sending you a moderator message explaining the reason why.

This is clearly a picture of Hitler and such material is not allowed on Buddhism SE.

Such an avatar:

- Depicts or promotes hate in any form and
- Insults, is insulting to or negatively objectifies those belonging to a certain race, gender or religion.

Please refrain from using such images on Buddhism SE in the future.

Comment: Where did you send the message? To my email because I never got anything here although it's not outside the realm of possibility that I missed it or something.

Comment: Hello Lanka, I appreciate all your feedback....            How does it promote hate? Why does it promote hate?  Where are you getting that? What is "such" images? I have no idea where your line that can't be crossed  is exactly so maybe all images uploaded should be checked by you first to make sure you agree before an image is uploaded?

Comment: @MettaforBullies If you read [this topic](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/243285/139866) (including all comments), moderators don't have "a clear policy about what sorts of images are inappropriate". Instead they must "discuss the problematic image in mod-only chat rooms, and in doubtful cases, consult the community team". However "the most common offenders seem to be explicit nudity and Nazi symbols".

Comment: @MettaforBullies. See the answer I just wrote.

Comment: @ChrisW There is no Nazi symbol. The purpose of the image isn't to offend anyone it's quite the opposite. Instead of asking me, you go ask other people! I mean that's just common courtesy. Even when I tell you what the thing is about you still say I can't upload it? You said you didn't think I was offending people, or something...I guess I read it wrong.

Comment: @ChrisW It's not a big deal. I must admit, I am merging you and Lanka together and that isn't fair. I can see your trying to do the right thing. Thank you. :)

Answer (score 0):

> Hello Lanka, I appreciate all your feedback....            How does it promote hate? Why does it promote hate?  Where are you getting that? What is "such" images? I have no idea where your line that can't be crossed  is exactly so maybe all images uploaded should be checked by you first to make sure you agree before an image is uploaded?

You are welcome.

As far as I know this is the first time a profile-picture has been checked and moderated in my time on Buddhism SE.

I had no experience regarding this issue so I asked in a chat room for all Stack Exchange Network moderators on how to proceed and if they knew about any guidelines/politics regarding inappropriate profile pictures.

Another moderator sent me the guideline [*"As a moderator, how do I handle a potentially inappropriate profile picture?"*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/243285/as-a-moderator-how-do-i-handle-a-potentially-inappropriate-profile-picture). Be sure to read it through, comments too. As you see there does not exist a rigid formular on how to deal with these things so in the end its a decision made by the moderator in agreement with other moderators from the same SE, e.g. Buddhism SE.

As ChrisW also mentions then images displaying *nudity and Nazi-symbols* are not welcome.

I also discussed the procedure with the other moderators which is to remove the inappropriate picture and sent a moderator message to the user explaining the reason behind the decision and give a warning.
If the user continues to upload inappropriate pictures then a timed suspension-period will follow.

Hope this helps.

Comment: A next step (or *another* step) might be to confirm with a community moderator (i.e. with Stack Exchange employee) whether the specific picture is acceptable? I think there's reason to find it questionable, at least ... and having to ask/bother an SE employee about this could be avoided, if the OP would simply desist from using this image.

Comment: @ChrisW. I agree. Answer edited.